# MinGW still pointing to old python version, even though the path has been removed

Tags: python, mingw

I uninstalled my python 3.10.9 and then I installed 3.11.2, the latest version, and yes I did add it to path when I installed it, did everything like before.
After restarting, I checked to see if all is good but python --version was not working so I found out I had to disable python from app execution alias or something like that.
Now python --version works, great, except it does not, it still shows 3.10.9.
I ran where python and it showed me two paths:
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
So I checked my environment variables and I saw the python311 path scripts being at the TOP followed by the basic python311 path, as far as I know that is how it should be right?
The mingw bin path was way below it, so why it points to that .exe instead of the new one?
I even removed the mingw bin path from the environment variables and restarted the system and absolutely no change...

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: @Nudam nope, i ended up staying on 3.10.9